# manage.py makemigrations ignores models.py

Tags: python, django, orm

Lately I've been working on a Django 4.1 app, and I've got a model with following fields:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
import datetime

class CarArticle(models.Model):

    class manufacturers(models.TextChoices):
        BMW = 'BMW', _('BMW')
        AUDI = 'AUDI', _('AUDI')
        LEXUS = 'LEX', _('LEXUS')
        MERCEDES = 'BENZ', _('MERCEDES')
        VOLKSWAGEN = 'VW', _('VOLKSWAGEN')
        VOLVO = 'VOLVO', _('VOLVO')
        FORD = 'FORD', _('FORD')
        SAAB = 'SAAB', _('SAAB')
        


    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    articleId = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        choices=manufacturers.choices
    )
    series = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gen = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mileage = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    engSize = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    fuelType = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    createdAt = models.DateField(auto_created = True,default=datetime.date.today)
    updatedAt = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Upon changing any field and running `py manage.py makemigrations`, I'm presented with `No changes detected`.

My `admin.py` looks like that:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *


admin.site.register(CarArticle)
```

Previously, I removed migrations files and folder since I've been remodeling the database over and over.

When I migrate with newly set database, I'm presented with these tables only:

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_capi_tool        |
+----------------------------+
| auth_group                 |
| auth_group_permissions     |
| auth_permission            |
| auth_user                  |
| auth_user_groups           |
| auth_user_user_permissions |
| django_admin_log           |
| django_content_type        |
| django_migrations          |
| django_session             |
+----------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Could deleting migrations folder with migrations file inside it screw up the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands?

ps my application is registered within `INSTALLED_APPS` as well

Comment: Can you check that your database have the base migrations (and not your delete migrations which contains the new model) ?

Comment: I think You just deleted the migartions folder, I think you should also delete the django_migrations table in your db and then run makemigrations again.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this was much simpler than I thought - Since the issue started happening after the removal of migrations folder - I took a deeper dive into documentation of this topic. There I found that migrations folder with `__init__.py` file is necessary for it to work, and therefore my issue is no more :)